# Scaling ASP.NET when using Bearer Tokens

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, bearer-token

I am building a ASP.NET Web API project that uses OWIN OAuth bearer token custom authentication.  I have the API working well for a single machine, but don't really understand how I would scale the API to multiple machines through a load balancer.  It seems that the machine that authenticates the user/password and provides the bearer token would be the only machine that would know how to authenticate that bearer token for future requests.  How can I set things up so that any machine behind the load balancer can authenticate the token?  I am pretty new to this kind of authentication so forgive me if my terminology is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the bearer token (or the jwt token) using the same audienceId and audience secret; thi way both the machine can validate them correctly.

I uses to keep them in my web.config file, for example like this:

```
<add key="as:AudienceId" value="localhost" />
<add key="as:AudienceSecret" value="YVZQUXd6VTZnWkpiR28wV0ROSTZCUzl1RzRRYTRnSDE=" />
```

Then you can use them to generate your jwt token:

```
internal class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    private readonly string _audienceId = SettingsProvider.CurrentAudienceId;
    private readonly string _issuer = SettingsProvider.CurrentIssuer;
    private readonly string _symmetricKeyAsBase64 = SettingsProvider.CurrentAudienceSecret;

    public String Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(_symmetricKeyAsBase64);
        var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);
        var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
        var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, _audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime,
            expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

        return jwt;
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(String protectedText)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Second, you need to use the same machine key in web.config on all you web farm machine, like this:

```
<machineKey validationKey="9E7EB24C628533D0F2A0B8CE2E740DD524472EA4A68C21325D007D15ED22E7DF81300BBE2AC70B6259CB41F22FA95AAFECA5BE8D72D8F7A80F13FCECE49DFFC1" decryptionKey="340A7B141479D146A50B59FAF7E4DD7218D6310B8D121178FFE3CE2AC198CD34" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Comment: In addition, to place machine key in the web.config file, looks like 

<system.webServer>
  <system.web>
 <machineKey validationKey="9AF5F9FCDF768D476DE86A0797964FDBAEE1578F3023E5DB29A5492049F53B3639E9C7B985A1D8A0338BCD0C55264DBBB00E8E0A9F7082C48C499619FC31CDD2"
 decryptionKey="E91D24732EACD69E2DB3E4E32BC4E6C87640D0F7B7D27A4AF7E07B9BA3BC8C54" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

You can generate a machine key on this link
- https://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx